# Dart - Split a timeframe into days

Tags: date, datetime, flutter, dart

I have two DateTimes indicating the start and the end of an event. I am trying to divide the time between these two dates into days:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.parse(event.startDate);
DateTime end = DateTime.parse(event.stopDate);
```

I tried making a while loop, and then calling `currentDate.add(Duration(days: 1))` until `currentDate.isBefore(end)` The difficulty I'm facing is that the start date can be for example at 16:00, then the first day should be from `16:00` to `00:00` today. Same thing for the final day, it can end at any time:

Example:

```
12:00 01.06.2019 - 9:00 03.06.2019
```

The result:

```
[(12:00 01.06.2019, 00:00 02.06.2019), (00:00 02.06.2019, 00:00 03.06.2019), (00:00 03.06.2019, 09:00 03.06.2019)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `add` as it may give misleading results when daylight time starts and finishes. It's safer to use the constructor with `day + 1`.

Try this:

```
main() {
  final start = DateTime(2019, 6, 1, 12);
  final end = DateTime(2019, 6, 3, 9);

  var midnight = DateTime(start.year, start.month, start.day);
  var nextMidnight = DateTime(midnight.year, midnight.month, midnight.day + 1);
  var endMidnight = DateTime(end.year, end.month, end.day);

  print('$start---$nextMidnight');

  do {
    midnight = nextMidnight;
    nextMidnight = DateTime(midnight.year, midnight.month, midnight.day + 1);
    print('$midnight---$nextMidnight');
  } while (nextMidnight.isBefore(endMidnight));

  print('$endMidnight---$end');
}
```